# How to customise polyline to look like Google Maps Android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

On adding `Polyline`, following is shown:
[image]

How o show the following?

[image]

Difference is in Border of polyline

Answer (score 2):

(Just search on 'polyline border' (in SO) and find numerous similar solutions - but I couldn't help trying it myself.)

For a border draw two PolyLines with varying width and color:

```
    PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions().add(latLng)
            .add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude+.05,latLng.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude+.07,latLng.longitude+.01))
            .add(new LatLng( latLng.latitude+.09, latLng.longitude+.02))
            .add(new LatLng(latLng.latitude+.09, latLng.longitude+.03));
    po.color(Color.BLACK).width(16);
    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);
    po.color(Color.CYAN).width(10);
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);
```

Results in:

[image]